# Notification button not loading on the top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

[image]

The message notification menu on the top bar seems broken.

Everything else seems ok, but not being able to read my notifications is bad.

Can we have it fixed please?

Comment: Additional information: The notifications load when checked in chat.

Comment: The drop down works on https://stackexchange.com

Comment: I can reproduce on both Firefox and Chrome (chromium) on Linux, but the menu works fine when you don't have any messages (my sock can open it).

Comment: I do run an unsupported chromium fork, so I doublechecked elsewhere before I posted. I can also read messages on the mobile app... which probably kinda works for me

Comment: Down voting still works for me ... Just checking for collateral damage ...

Comment: Should be back, but we're still investigating the cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yesterday, we pushed a change to clean up some site settings that are used by both public Q&A and Teams. When the changes pushed out, the public Q&A changes were successful, but the Teams build failed - which was unknown to the developers.

The failure put Teams in an inconsistent state which took it offline. We pushed a build to Teams again which put things in the correct state and things came back online.

Now you're probably wondering why this impacted the top bar notifications?

When checking the global inbox/notifications, we also check for Teams items. Since Teams was offline, the inbox items couldn't be checked - resulting in the global inbox/notifications to not load. Once the build was fixed, so was the top bar notifications and inbox.